# Преобразовать дату Yyyy-mm-dd в число недели php

Tags: php

Есть дата, записанная в строковую переменную, например, `$mydate` - выглядит она примерно так: `2016-01-18`.

Как её преобразовать в порядковое число недели, которое генерируется функцией `date("W")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mydate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-01-18');
$week  = $mydate->format('W');
```

В итоге, `$week` будет равно `03`

Comment: а скажите пожалуйста обратно так можно? то есть 03 неделю в Y-m-d

Comment: я тут тоже погуглил там минимум по мимо дня недели надо год еще указать\ вот такое нашел тут [http://www.sql.ru/forum/434923/php-data-nachala-i-konca-nedeli](http://www.sql.ru/forum/434923/php-data-nachala-i-konca-nedeli) ну... если еще кому то нужно будет)

Comment: @dantelol Добавил функцию с обратным преобразованием

Answer (score 0):

```
$tempDate = '2016-01-18';
echo date('l', strtotime($tempDate));
```

Выводит: *Monday*

```
$tempDate = '2016-01-18';
echo date('W', strtotime($tempDate));
```

Выводит: *03*

Answer (score 0):

**Обратное приобразование.**

Функция возврашает массив с первым и последним днем недели.

```
<?php

function getWeekDates($year, $week, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $year . '-01-01');
    $d->add(new DateInterval('P' . $week .'W'));
    $dow = (integer) $d->format('N');
    $startDate = clone $d;
    $endDate = clone $d;

    $endDate->add(new DateInterval('P' . (7 - $dow) . 'D'));
    $startDate->sub(new DateInterval('P' . ($dow -1) . 'D'));

    return [
        'start' => $startDate->format($format),
        'end' => $endDate->format($format)
    ];
}

var_dump(getWeekDates(2016, 4));
```